# Не могу отправить SQL запросы циклом в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Если я делаю только один запрос вне цикла, то все замечательно работает, к примеру:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ochr_category` (`category_id`, `parent_id`, `top`, `column`, `sort_order`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`) VALUES ('9999999', '321', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2019-03-04 19:43:43', '2019-03-04 19:43:43')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Но если в цикле:

```
foreach ($name as $key) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO `ochr_category` (`category_id`, `parent_id`, `top`, `column`, `sort_order`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`) VALUES ('${$key[id]}', '321', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2019-03-04 19:43:43', '2019-03-04 19:43:43')";
  mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

то выдает ошибку -

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

$name - это асоциативный массив, $link - ссылка на бд.
Подключение к бд есть, так как один запрос без проблем отправляется.

Более подробный код:

```
define('DB_HOST', '***');
define('DB_USER', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_NAME', '***');

global $link;

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");

$catalog = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$categories = $catalog->shop->categories->category;

get_category($categories);

 function get_category($name){
  foreach ($name as $key) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `ochr_category` (`category_id`, `parent_id`, `top`, `column`, `sort_order`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`) VALUES ('${$key[id]}', '321', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2019-03-04 19:43:43', '2019-03-04 19:43:43')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
  }
}
```

Comment: Лучше покажите весь код. Ошибка говорит только об одном, переменная $link на момент выполнения запроса пуста. в приведенных строках не видно что бы что то ее очищало, значит это делают какие то строки перед циклом, например. Или вы плюс ко всему завернули это в функцию, а global забыли

Comment: Добавил более подробный код

Comment: Либо `global $link;` внутрь функции, либо передавать его в нее параметром. Второй вариант правильный, первый - костыль.

Comment: Да, передал $link в качестве параметра и все заработало, спасибо! Нужно будет разобраться получше с областями видимости в php)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался! Нужно просто передать $link, как параметр функции get_category.